# XAMPP Not working with PHP includes?

Tags: php, include, xampp, localhost

I've installed XAMPP on my laptop and followed so many different words of advise on this problem but none fix it.

My PHP includes do not show at all on the page.

I've created a folder in the HTPDOCS in XAMPP folder called mysite, when I go to localhost/ it shows the xampp index page fine. When I type localhost/mysite/index.php I get my page but my styles are an include which is includes/styles.php and that contains all my style sheets which are placed in the head of my index.php.

I've tried changing the my ports on skype and that doesn't help.

Any idea on what else I may need to do if I want my include files to start working?

Thanks in advance, hope this is enough info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this include in your index.php:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . "/includes/styles.php";
```

Comment: is this also okay to use when I add my site to my server or will I have to go through and change all my includes throughout my whole site

Comment: This will be okey on your server.